# A group of extremely pious folks

Tags: talmud-gemara

In the Talmud, I think it is in berachos, there is mentioned a group of extremely pious people. Does anyone know the name of this group?

Comment: So it could be anywhere in the Talmud?

Answer (score 8):

There is not much information in the question to go on, so this is hardly a definitive answer, but perhaps you are referring to the following:

**[Berachot 9b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=9b&format=pdf)**

> העיד ר"י בן אליקים משום קהלא קדישא דבירושלים כל הסומך גאולה לתפלה אינו
>   נזוק כל היום כולו
>
> R. Jose b. Eliakim testified in the name of the holy community of
>   Jerusalem: If one joins the ge'ullah to the tefillah, he will not meet
>   with any mishap for the whole of the day. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

Thus, the group is called קהלא קדישא דבירושלים, or The Holy Community of Jerusalem.

There is another group mentioned on [the same page](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=9b&format=pdf):

> אמר אביי לתפילין כאחרים לק"ש כותיקין דאמר ר' יוחנן ותיקין היו גומרין
>   אותה עם הנץ החמה תניא נמי הכי ותיקין היו גומרין אותה עם הנץ החמה כדי
>   שיסמוך גאולה לתפלה ונמצא מתפלל ביום
>
> Abaye says: In regard to the tefillin, the halachah is as stated by
>   the ‘Others’; in regard to [the recital of] the Shema’, as practised
>   by the watikin. For R. Johanan said: The watikin used to finish it
>   [the recital of the Shema’] with sunrise, in order to join the
>   ge'ullah with the tefillah, and say the tefillah in the daytime.
>   ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

Here the name of the group is ותיקין, or Watikin. It is not entirely clear who/what this refers to. [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) explains it as referring to humble men to whom the commandment is dear:

> אנשים ענוים ומחבבין מצוה

The footnote in the above translation states:

> Lit., strong’ (sc.,in piety), a title probably applied to certain men
>   who, in the time of the Hasmonean kingdom, set an example of
>   exceptional piety. Some identify them with the Essenes.

Alternatively, you might be referring to the following:

**[Berachot 32b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=32b&format=pdf)**

> תנו רבנן חסידים הראשונים היו שוהין שעה אחת ומתפללין שעה אחת וחוזרין
>   ושוהין שעה אחת וכי מאחר ששוהין תשע שעות ביום בתפלה תורתן היאך משתמרת
>   ומלאכתן היאך נעשית אלא מתוך שחסידים הם תורתם משתמרת ומלאכתן מתברכת
>
> Our Rabbis taught: The pious men of old used to wait for an hour and
>   pray for an hour and then wait again for an hour. But seeing that they
>   spend nine hours a day over prayer, how is their knowledge of Torah
>   preserved and how is their work done? [The answer is] that because
>   they are pious, their Torah is preserved and their work is blessed.
>   ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

In this case the name of the group is חסידים הראשונים, or The Pious Men of Old.

Answer (score 3):

Not in ברכות, but given the very vague parameters of the question, might it be the 36 [hidden righteous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzadikim_Nistarim) mentioned in Sanhedrin 97b and Sukka 45b?

> Abaye said: The world has no fewer than thirty-six righteous people in
>   each generation who greet the Divine Presence

Answer (score 1):

A group of pious people called the "vatikin" (ותיקין) are mentioned on Berakhot 26a.  As Rashi puts it, they are people who try extra hard to do mitzvot in their proper time, at the earliest possible.

Comment: This group is already mentioned in the other earlier answer

Comment: @DoubleAA https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2087/9682